# Updating Listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need to update each item row after it is added to `listView`.I am using `abc_slide_in_bottom` for animation

All I want is that when an item is added to the `ListView` after sliding from bottom the previous item `TextView`(having some text value) should change to `ImageView`.

MainActivity:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dataObj=new Data();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_preFlight);
    goBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    context=this.getApplicationContext();

    setData();//to add first item to the dataObj
    customAdapter=new dataListAdapter(dataObj,context,MainActivity.this);

    myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   LayoutAnimationController lac = new LayoutAnimationController(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.abc_fade_in), 2f);
    myListView.setLayoutAnimation(lac);

}
```

i am calling onUpdate whenever a new item is added to the ListView,to update the old item.
OnUpdate function in MainActivity

```
  public void onUpdate(int position)
{
    View v=myListView.getChildAt(position);

        if(v!=null)
        {
            TextView titleTV=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemName);
            TextView statusTV=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemStatus);
            ImageView imageIV=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
            if(statusTV.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            {
                Log.e(dataListAdapter.TAG,"pos "+position+" title: "+titleTV.getText());
                statusTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
        dataObj.itemName.add(items[position+1]);
        dataObj.status.add("Checking...");
        dataObj.showImg.add(false);
        customAdapter=new dataListAdapter(dataObj ,context,MainActivity.this);
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        count++;


}
```

Here i have added custom adapter with Listview.
My custom Adapter's getView method:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preflight_row_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemName);
    holder.status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemStatus);
    holder.img=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
    holder.title.setText(Title.get(position));
    holder.status.setText(Status.get(position));
    holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick_image);

    if (position+1==this.Title.size())//when new item added call to onUpdate
    {

        update.onUpdate(position);//customListner's function called
    }

    return (row);
}
```

The `row_layout.xml` contains 2 `TextView`s for Item title, item status(as "checking....") and a `ImageView`.
I am trying to update previous item in `ListView` from  the "checking...." `TextView` to `ImageView` when the new item gets added to the `ListView`.
My requirement kind of matches to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854955/android-listview-item-change-after-10-seconds-automatically) but i am not able to update old item,Moreover items are added randomly to listview

Comment: I already tried solving with the way you have given response.But did not work.I am now trying to do it with asynctask and updating view in onPostExecute

Comment: check this class, feeling lazy to correct some things, but this should give you what you want, maybe [link](http://pastebin.com/EfFK9R3D)

Comment: @Elltz not got any sol yet :(

Comment: hey Sir, too late, did the class help you? the link i posted?

Answer (score 0):

get a reference to your `Animation` and set a listener on it

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // here the animation has ended
           // so you call notifydatasetchanged here, so before you add
           // an item to the list update needs to be true; so after the
          // getView method it is false;
        }
    });
```

now from how i am thinking now you put a logic to that, this is my logic to you, when an item is added to a `ListView` its added to the data object that backs it, if yours its an `ArrayList` then its the last item in the list, so in your `getView` you can check for your last item in the `List` and add modifications to it, an the modifications here will be in your `getView` method to update that particular item, to eliminate the updating of the last item everytime, you can add `boolean` to check if an item has been added, **or** you can put that `boolean` as a field in your data object so you check for it and toggle it to false then you change that `View`

**Edit 1**
your custom data object

```
public class Data{
String title,nxtstatus,prevstatus; boolean update;
//any additional stuff can go here depends on you
}
```

then you will use an `ArrayList`, `ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();` then you create another class for your `View`s like this `public class MyViews { TextView title, status,prevStatus; ImageView prevImg;}`
then in your `getView` method

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View row = convertView;
MyViews myv; // you might be required to initialize this
Data data = getItem(position); //getItem is a super class's method
if(row == null){
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
myv = new MyViews();
myv.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemName);
myv.status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemStatus);
myv.prevImg=(ImageView)newRow.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
myv.prevImg.setVisibiltiy(View.GONE);
title.setText(data.title);
status.setText(data.status);
row.setTag(myv);}else{myv = row.getTag(); //some casting will go on here    
}    
if(data.update){ // if update is true it means it was just added
   myv.prevStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
   myv.prevImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   data.update = false; // the next pass this view will not be updated
}
//then finally return the row;
return row;}
```

i think that's enough to get you going, go to the animation code on top pretty basic right?

Comment: did not work means it didin't even try somehow to work? why do you have this line? `View newRow=(View) rowView.get(position-1);` from how i see this line you will never get the last item to update, if you were playing with the actual size of the data object then you go `-1` from it, am i lucid? @user3207655

Comment: the list goes from 0 to n-1 so Therefore used condition postion>0.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: actually the issue here is i am returning row(which contains the "checking.. "textView) from getView while i require that it should update the previous row with image and add new row with "checking.." textView

Comment: yes you are right it starts from 0 to n-1, so the position is (n-1) and you were doing (n-1)-1) and yes you are right you should have putting also this line in your if statement `row= newrow` , so you have solved it ? or give me your status Sir@user3207655

Comment: no not solved..the items are sliding from bottom to top with 1st two coming as "checking.." while rest with image :(

Comment: I think there's some issue with approach itself...what i need from the get view method is `row` and the `newrow` both

Comment: yea your approach is bad, first you dont save the view in an array, okay so all i will say is get rid of the rowView array and use a custom object that is going to store your status and your title and also a boolean that you are going to check in an if statement if its true then you set the visibility of the imageview to visible, let me see if i can give a sample hold up@user3207655